# Отслеживание состояния сервиса Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service

Пишу приложение под Android которое состоит из activity и привязанной к ней службе. Вопрос состоит в следующем: как можно уведомить пользователя о том, в каком состоянии находится служба? К примеру, у службы есть несколько состояний: connected, disconnected, sleep и busy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вы можете показать Toast сообщение прямо из Service, так как у Service есть Context
2. Вы можете настроить общение между Activity и Service. Подробнее об этом можете почитать в [этой статье](https://medium.com/the-sixt-india-blog/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297).

Answer (score 0):

Один из правильных вариантов -> [Notification](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications?hl=ru)